# Database modal for form

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a Database so i can automatically fill a form. But i don't know how i have to setup the database.

I want to create forms for a specific `websiteID` and add to that website multiple `Categories` with `Items` attached to that categorie.

Here is my database right now:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblWebsite` (
  `websiteId` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `websiteNaam` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `websiteUrl` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tblCategories` (
      `categorieId` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `websiteId` int NOT NULL,
      `categorieName` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tblItems` (
          `itemId` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `categorieId` int NOT NULL,
          `itemName` varchar(255) NOT NULL
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

For example: `itemId 1` is in `categorieId 1` for `websiteId 1`
So when I select `websiteId 1` I want to show both `categorieName` and `itemName` for that website. Will it work with this database setup?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly for Normalisation, You want to create link tables between Website and Categories and Categories and Items. Because a Website can have many Categories and Categories can be associated to many Websites. Same with and Categories and Items.

Please see new Database structure(Also excuse my bad MySql skills).

```
CREATE TABLE `tblWebsite` (
  `websiteId` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `websiteNaam` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `websiteUrl` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tblCategories` (
      `categorieId` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `categorieName` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tblWebsiteCategories` (
      `websiteId` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `categorieId`  int(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`websiteId`,`categorieId`),
        UNIQUE KEY `FK_tblWebsite_websiteId` (`websiteId`),
        UNIQUE KEY `FK_tblCategories_categorieId` (`categorieId`),
        CONSTRAINT `FK_tblWebsiteCategories_Website` FOREIGN KEY (`websiteId`) REFERENCES `tblWebsite` (`websiteId`),
        CONSTRAINT `FK_tblWebsiteCategories_Categories` FOREIGN KEY (`categorieId`) REFERENCES `tblCategories` (`categorieId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tblItems` (
          `itemId` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `itemName` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `tblCategorieItems` (
      `categorieId` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `itemId`  int(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`categorieId`,`itemId`),
        UNIQUE KEY `FK_tblCategories_categorieId` (`categorieId`),
        UNIQUE KEY `FK_tblCategories_itemId` (`itemId`),
        CONSTRAINT `FK_tblCategorieItems_Categories` FOREIGN KEY (`categorieId`) REFERENCES `tblCategories` (`categorieId`),
        CONSTRAINT `FK_tblCategorieItems_Items` FOREIGN KEY (`itemId`) REFERENCES `tblItems` (`itemId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then your SELECT Statement.

```
SELECT c.CategorieName,
  i.itemName
FROM tblWebsiteCategories wc
INNER JOIN tblCategories c
  ON c.categorieId = wc.categorieId
INNER JOIN tblCategorieItems ci
  ON ci.categorieId = c.categorieId
INNER JOIN tblItems i
  ON ci.itemId = i.itemId
WHERE wc.websiteId = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll save yourself a lot of pain if you work out the schema of your database visually using a tool like https://www.lucidchart.com/.

The operation you want to do is a `JOIN` between tables on your various ID variables. That should work fine with your schema, but to make it more robust you should use `FOREIGN KEY`s. For example, you should make `categorieId` in `tblItems` a `FOREIGN KEY` to `categorieId` in `tblCategories`. This will ensure that every item in `tblItems` has a valid `categorieId` which can link it to `tblCategories`.